# How to get remaining storage of Google Picasa account using API?

Tags: c#, picasa

How to get remaining storage of Google Picasa account using API?

I used this code but did not see any bytesused tag

```
FeedQuery query = new FeedQuery();
        PicasaService service = new PicasaService("xanaxzxzx");
        // Set your credentials:
        service.setUserCredentials(username, password);

        // Create the query object:
        query.Uri = new Uri(String.Format("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/{0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username)));

        // Tell the service to query:
        AtomFeed calFeed = service.Query(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is two years old question, but for anyone who still finding, the answer is here:

> To obtain the amount of quota remaining, subtract the
>   feed/gphoto:quotacurrent from the feed/gphoto:quotalimit value found
>   in the following feed:
>       https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/username
>
> ```
> The word default can be used in place of the username if you're using an authentication token.
> ```

Taken from:
https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/faq#quota

Comment: Can you post answer here? (in additional to link)